# ActiveSupport::Notifications transaction_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, transactions, notifications

I have been browsing the Rails repository at Github to find the definition of transaction_id, but is unsuccessful.

What kind of transaction is it? It looks like the same transaction_id is used for a group of events.

```
ActiveSupport::Notifications.subscribe do |name, start, finish, transaction_id , payload|
  Rails.logger.debug(["notification:", name, start, finish, transaction_id , payload].join(" "))
end
```

Result:

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-10-16 15:51:40 +0200

notification: sql.active_record 2012-10-16 15:51:40 +0200 2012-10-16 15:51:40 +0200 9eb707034598e4cc7c32 {:sql=>"SHOW client_min_messages", :name=>"SCHEMA", :connection_id=>46235640, :binds=>[]}

notification: sql.active_record 2012-10-16 15:51:40 +0200 2012-10-16 15:51:40 +0200 9eb707034598e4cc7c32 {:sql=>"SET client_min_messages TO 'panic'", :name=>"SCHEMA", :connection_id=>46235640, :binds=>[]}

notification: sql.active_record 2012-10-16 15:51:40 +0200 2012-10-16 15:51:40 +0200 9eb707034598e4cc7c32 {:sql=>"SET standard_conforming_strings = on", :name=>"SCHEMA", :connection_id=>46235640, :binds=>[]}

notification: sql.active_record 2012-10-16 15:51:40 +0200 2012-10-16 15:51:40 +0200 9eb707034598e4cc7c32 {:sql=>"SET client_min_messages TO 'notice'", :name=>"SCHEMA", :connection_id=>46235640, :binds=>[]}

notification: sql.active_record 2012-10-16 15:51:40 +0200 2012-10-16 15:51:40 +0200 9eb707034598e4cc7c32 {:sql=>"SET time zone 'UTC'", :name=>"SCHEMA", :connection_id=>46235640, :binds=>[]}

...

notification: process_action.action_controller 2012-10-16 15:51:40 +0200 2012-10-16 15:51:41 +0200 9eb707034598e4cc7c32 {:controller=>"PagesController", :action=>"index", :params=>{"controller"=>"pages", "action"=>"index"}, :format=>:html, :method=>"GET", :path=>"/", :status=>200, :view_runtime=>339.344333, :db_runtime=>31.421587}
```

The same transaction_id: 9eb707034598e4cc7c32

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just dove deep into this, hoping that there was some way to get the request from within a LogSubscriber.  No such luck.

Activesupport::Notifications::Instrumenter has a unique id, initialized as a SecureRandom.hex(10) when it is initialized.  Any evernt created by this instrumenter gets that 10 digit hex id.

In ActiveSupport::Notifications, the instrumenter is picked out of Thread.current, and created if none exists - therefore all notifications sent within the scope of a single thread will have the same transaction_d, unifying them all together (which is nice), but the initial value of that transaction_id is simply a 10 digit random hex. (defined in Activesupport::Notifications::Instrumenter#unique_id)

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the event's `transaction_id` to `ActiveSupport::Notifications.instrumenter.id`!

This was solved sometime between 2013 and 2023.

```
transaction_id = ActiveSupport::Notifications.instrumenter.id

subscriber =
  ActiveSupport::Notifications.monotonic_subscribe(
    'sql.active_record',
  ) do |event|
    next unless event.transaction_id == transaction_id
    # Do something with event.payload
end
```